# How to get ci user name in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I provide a python application ran in gitlab ci for my team members. This application needs to get the ci username and send it to my backend storage.
For now I tried,

1. GitLab predefined variable GITLAB_USER_LOGIN

But this environment variable could be modify by anyone. It's not safe.

2. GitLab CI_JOB_TOKEN

CI_JOB_TOKEN's scope is limited to some API endpoints ([doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html)), I can't access https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/ to obain user detail by CI_JOB_TOKEN in gitlab ci.

I don't want to ask users to set personal access token or any extra information. How to get the ci username by gitlab ci primitive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GitLab Jobs API ([doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-job-tokens-job)).

Get the job that generated the job's token

```
GET /job
```

Example:

```
curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/job
```

Response:

```
{
  ...

  "commit": {
    ...
  },
  "pipeline": {
    ...
  }
  "project": {
    ...
  },
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Administrator",
    "username": "root"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get last pipeline id from related project:

[documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines)

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

Sample output:

```
 {
    "id": 48,
    "iid": 13,
    "project_id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "source": "web",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "eb94b618fb5865b26e80fdd8ae531b7a63ad851a",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/48",
    "created_at": "2016-08-12T10:06:04.561Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-12T10:09:56.223Z"
  }
```

Example:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines" | jq '.[0].id
```

Then put it in this API:

[documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline)

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "id": 46,
  "iid": 11,
  "project_id": 1,
  "status": "success",
  "ref": "main",
  "sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
  "before_sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
  "tag": false,
  "yaml_errors": null,
  "user": {
    "name": "Administrator",
    "username": "root",
    "id": 1,
    "state": "active",
    "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
    "web_url": "http://localhost:3000/root"
  },
  "created_at": "2016-08-11T11:28:34.085Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.169Z",
  "started_at": null,
  "finished_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.145Z",
  "committed_at": null,
  "duration": 123.65,
  "queued_duration": 0.010,
  "coverage": "30.0",
  "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/46"
}
```

Example:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/46" | jq '.user.username'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It works. I can get username by one request with GitLab Jobs API.